# Bash Command to Show Pids of Processes Spawned

Tags: c, bash, shell

I've been looking through bash command documentation and I can't seem to find anything to solve this problem.

Your shell shall support the shopped command
to list the PIDs of the last 10 processes spawned by your shell.

The best I've been able to do is [ ps T -o pid ] which only shows pids of the current running processes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67635/elegantly-get-list-of-children-processes *Helpful?*

Comment: The spec "..to list the PIDs of the last 10 processes spawned by your shell" does not indicate that the last 10 processes spawned are "still alive" which would mean pstree would work only if they are still alive.

Comment: Are you quoting an assignment in the second paragraph? `bash` doesn't provide anything like this, but it would be trivial to implement if you are writing a shell: every time you start a new process, add its ID to a list.

Comment: You probably heard `shopt`, not "shopped"